# Coloring 3 regions of a plot in R

Tags: r, function, plot, polygon

I have a plot in which there are two curved lines (below).

I was wondering if there is way to color above the top line in **red**, between the two lines in **yellow**, and below the bottom line in **green**?

My desired plot as well as my reproducible code is below.

```
f <- function(x,peak_x=10,peak_y=11,coef=.004) coef*-(x-peak_x)^2+peak_y
a <- curve(f,0,65,ylim=c(0,11))
b <- curve(f(x, peak_y = 6,coef = .003),0,65, col=3,add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: As a general strategy, I think you will need to use the values returned by those `curve` calls to build polygons that you can fill with colors. Look at `str(a)` and `str(b)` as starting points. Can't do any further work because dinner calls.

Comment: @IRTFM, you're exactly right. But would you please write an answer when you get a chance?

Comment: I'm puzzled. @thelatemail already posted one that's pretty much waht I imagined. If it's not clear how he did it, I'd be happy to insert an explanation by editing his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer may be obtained using:

```
a <- curve(f,-3,65,ylim=c(0,12),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
pusr <- par("usr")
rect(pusr[1], pusr[3], pusr[2], pusr[4], col=2,border = 1)
b <- curve(f(x, peak_y = 6,coef = .003),-3,65,add=TRUE,col=2)


polygon(c(-3,a$x,63),c(0,a$y,f(63)),col="yellow")
polygon(c(-3,b$x,54),c(-3,b$y,f(55, peak_y = 6,coef = .003)),col=3)
box()
```

[image]

Comment: Finally got around to fixing my answer. See above.

Comment: @thelatemail, happy to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably several ways, but `polygon` is nice:

```
## define function
f <- function(x, peak_x, peak_y, coef) coef * -(x - peak_x)^ 2 + peak_y

## base plot
plot(NA, type="l", xlim=c(0,65), ylim=c(0,11))

## coordinates of user plotting space
pusr <- par("usr")

## x points to cover the whole area
x <- seq(pusr[1], pusr[2], length.out=101)

## then plot the polygons associated with the curves
rect(pusr[1], pusr[3], pusr[2], pusr[4], col=2)
polygon(x = c(x, pusr[1]), y = c(f(x, 10, 11, 0.004), pusr[3]), col="yellow")
polygon(x = c(x, pusr[1]), y = c(f(x, 10,  6, 0.003), pusr[3]), col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Upon scrutiny, I realized your regions are not exact. As @IRTFM noted ideally we would want to use the `x` and `y` given by the curve call to precisely create the colored regions.

Comment: @SimonHarmel I do not understand why the regions are "not exact".

Comment: You can increase the `length.out=` parameter but it should be pretty close to exact with 50 points. `curve` just plots a line with 101 points if you want to match it exactly. @simonharmel

Comment: @IRTFM, simply compare the 3 regions in my original post (red, yellow, green) and their borderline and where they touch the x-axis, then the differences between the expected plot vs. the current answer becomes more clear. For instance, compare the green region in the posted answer with the corresponding yellow region in my own post.